# code inside function declaration not run on rendering of react function component

Tags: reactjs

In the following react code, the code inside function declaration do not run when the component mounts. I think it should first assign the function body to fun and in this process it should console log ("hello inside declaration") and assign i to 5, but it is not the case.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {

  let i = 0

  let fun = () => {
    i = 5;
    console.log("hello inside declaration")
    return i;
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello inside use effect");
  });
  
  console.log("hello after");
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{i}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The output of console is -

```
hello after 
hello inside use effect
```

I know if i invoke the function, "hello inside declaration" will be printed in console but why not without invoking it.
Check the output here. https://codesandbox.io/s/learning-useeffect-7zu2x9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't call any functions unless explicitly asked to. The code that you provide assigns a method to the "fun" variable every time it renders the component, and that's it. If you want to call it when the component is mounted, you need to call it inside useEffect.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {

  let i = 0

  let fun = () => {
    i = 5;
    console.log("hello inside declaration")
    return i;
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello inside use effect");
    fun();
  }, []);
  
  console.log("hello after");
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{i}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Going further, your variable i won't be displayed as 5. Why is that? Is not a react state, and it doesn't tell react that something changed, and I want you to show it to me. Simply, it will just show 0 and then assign 5 to variable i, and that's all.

Number 5 will be shown on the site if you put it in the state.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [i, setI] = useState(0);

  let fun = () => {
    setI(5);
    console.log("hello inside declaration")
    return i;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello inside use effect");
    fun();
  }, []);

  console.log("hello after");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{i}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```